# EFUtilities with EFProfiler running

Tags: sql, entity-framework-6

I was wondering if there was a way to get EFUtilities running at the same time EFProfiler is running.

I appreciate the profiler would not show the bulk insert due to it being done outside the confines of DBContext.  At the moment, I cannot run batch jobs as the profiler has the connection wrapped. It Runs fine when not enabled

The exception I am getting is thus:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.Utilities.dll
>
> Additional information: No provider supporting the InsertAll operation
>   for this datasource was found

The inner exception is null.

Comment: Can you post the exception you are getting? I don't have EFProfiler but if it's related to the connection I can give you a solution. If they block some other part it might be harder.

Comment: added more detail upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because EFUtilities automatically finds the correct provider. But when the connection is wrapped this is no longer possible.

InsertAll looks like this.

```
public void InsertAll<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> items, DbConnection connection = null, int? batchSize = null)
```

To use the SqlProvider (which is actually the only provider out of the box) you can create a new SqlConnection() and pass that to insert all.

So basically you would need to do this:

```
        using (var db = new YourContext())
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
        {
            EFBatchOperation.For(db, db.PartialTestClass1).InsertAll(partials, con);
        }
```

Now, maybe you are doing more and want both parts to run under the same transaction. In that case you can wrap that code block in a TransactionScope.

Comment: I missed the argument where you could pass in your own connection string. Thanks a lot.